# Cant stop audio on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have problem with stoping audio player on click. Player starts successfully but im unable to stop it when i click again. Can you please help me with that ? Here is a code:

```
$(".portfolio-listen").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var audioUrl = $(this).attr("href");
  var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
  audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioUrl);
  $(this).toggleClass("playing");

  if ($(this).hasClass("playing")) {
    audioElement.play();
  } else {
    audioElement.pause();
  }


});
```

Comment: You create a new audio player with every click, and I think you have an issue with `toggleClass()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example could get more complex if you wish to load a new audio source depending on the button clicked, but make the audio element global and check if it's defined then proceed with toggling the audio play/pause.

```js
// for demo purpose, use var audioUrl = $(this).href('href')
var audioUrl = 'https://allthingsaudio.wikispaces.com/file/view/Shuffle%20for%20K.M.mp3/139190697/Shuffle%20for%20K.M.mp3';

// Make audioElement global
var audioElement;


$(".portfolio-listen").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
 
  if(!audioElement){
      audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
      audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioUrl);
  }
  
  $(this).toggleClass("playing");
  
  if ($(this).hasClass("playing")) {
    audioElement.play();
  } else {
    audioElement.pause();
  }


});
```

```css
button {
   background: #e91e63;
}
button.playing {
   background: #8bc34a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="portfolio-listen">Play</button>
```

Comment: Thank you :) Works perfect!